# zeros of a multi-valued function

Tags: complex-analysis, roots, riemann-surfaces

Consider the equation below

$$ z -1 - \left( \frac{1}{\sqrt{z^2+z + 1}} - \frac{2}{\sqrt{z^2 + 4}} \right) = 0. $$

The function on the lhs is a four-valued function. To get its zeros, we can convert it into a 12th order polynomial equation by squaring.

Then we will get 12 zeros.

The question is then, are all these zeros indeed zeros of the original equation? More precisely, for each of them, is it always possible to make the function on the lhs vanish by taking the signs of the square roots correctly?

Is there any general theory for such kind of problem?

Comment: No. In this case, the $12$ roots will not be distinct, they will be repeated roots, because the only solution of $(f(x))^n = 0$ is $f(x) = 0$ for $n \in \mathbb{N}$, so the extra roots will come in groups of equal roots. You can check this either by yourself, or in Wolfram Alpha. By the way, what does this question immediately have to do with Riemann surfaces?

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг It has to do somehow because the two-branched square root function gives rise to a Riemann surface, "wrapping" both sheets one over the other. There's a nice explanation in pages 4-6 here: http://scipp.ucsc.edu/~haber/ph116A/ComplexFunBranchTheory.pdf

Comment: @DonAntonio Thank you for the reference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. Let $u = \sqrt {z^2+z+1}$ and $v = \sqrt {z^2+4}$, so that we have $u^2 = z^2+z+1$ and $v^2=z^2+4$.

Your equation $z-1-1/u+2/v = 0$ is equivalent to $(z-1)uv-v+2u = 0$.

Now if you want to get an equation that only talks about $z$ from this, you have to multiply $(z-1)uv-v+2u$ with its conjugates.

In terms of Galois theory, $\Bbb C(z)[u,v]$ is a Galois extension of $\Bbb C(z)$, its Galois group is isomorphic to $(\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z)^2$ and is generated by $(u,v) \mapsto (-u,v)$ and $(u,v) \mapsto (u,-v)$.

Taking the norm of $(z-1)uv-v+2u$ will give you the expression
$((z-1)uv-v+2u)(-(z-1)uv-v-2u)(-(z-1)uv+v+2u)((z-1)uv+v-2u)$

This is invariant when you replace $u$ with $-u$ or $v$ with $-v$, so when you expand it and simplify, it is a polynomial expression in $z,u^2,v^2$.
Now you can replace $u^2,v^2$ with the corresponding polynomials in $z$, and you get that this product is actually a degree $12$ polynomial in $z$ (probably the same one that you've got).

Now, if $z$ is a root of the degree $12$ polynomial, and if you pick for $u$ and $v$ any of their two corresponding values and plug everything into the product, since the product evaluates to $0$, you must have that at least one of its factors also evaluates to zero. This means that there must be a choice for $u$ and $v$ that makes the original expression evaluate to $0$.

Comment: amazing! I encountered this problem in some quantum mechanics problem. I never expected that it has something to do with the Galois theory. So, is there any reference on this kind of problem? I mean not the Galois theory.